# Confusion on C++ prime plus example for dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, dynamic

I was currently reading C++ prime plus in order to learn dynamic memory allocate. I tried a piece of code on the book, but after I added one line after it I was confused by what I got: I asked the computer to print out p3[2] after I freed the memory for p3 and the computer actually printed out the correct value for p3. But shouldn't it be NOT possible for it to print after you free the memory already?

Here is the code:

```
// arraynew.cpp -- using the new operator for arrays
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    double * p3 = new double [3]; // space for 3 doubles
    p3[0] = 0.2; // treat p3 like an array name
    p3[1] = 0.5;
    p3[2] = 0.8;

    cout << "p3[1] is " << p3[1] << ".\n";
    p3 = p3 + 1; // increment the pointer
    cout << "Now p3[0] is " << p3[0] << " and ";
    cout << "p3[1] is " << p3[1] << ".\n";
    cout << "p3[2] is " << p3[2] << ".\n";

    p3 = p3 - 1; // point back to beginning
    delete [] p3; // free the memory
    cout << "p3[2] is " << p3[2] << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZ9ZB.png)

```
p3[1] is 0.5.
Now p3[0] is 0.5 and p3[1] is 0.8.
p3[2] is 6.95326e-310.
p3[2] is 0.8.
```

Comment: Please post the actual text of the output, not a screenshot. (I have edited it for you this time, since the output is quite small).

Comment: You've experienced undefined behaviour. And as the wordings says, the result of doing such things is undefined.

Comment: its actually C++ Primer Plus

Answer (score 5):

Once you deallocate memory the contents become invalidated. This does not mean that they are necessarily deleted - this would be a waste of resources for the operating system. Deallocation usually means that the operating system is free to use this memory whenever some other process requests HEAP memory - if you try to access this memory in the meanwhile it is highly likely that you will find the original contents there, as you did.

That said, trying to access memory that you have deallocated is undefined behaviour. There is no guarantee at all that you will find the original contents there, nor that they will be immediately deleted. Anything could happen so DON'T DO THIS!

Comment: Oh okay got it now. I will bear that in mind. Thanks for the explanation, Marinos!

Comment: I experienced another case where is not UB, but program simply _crash_ when dereferencing the pointer pointing to deallocated area. Could you explain what is going on there?

Comment: "dereferencing the pointer pointing to deallocated area" IS UB! Btw, a simple crash is the most common effect of UB.